# Meteor - event on new DOM element

Tags: jquery, events, meteor

I have a problem with event in meteor app.
I have a place in code  for "active" person.
When that person stopa being active a new person appears
I need to get the ID of that person on click

```
'click .person .fa-close': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var getid = $(event.target);
    console.log(getid.data('id'));
}
```

On the first click I will get correct data id, but when the new person with a new id shows up, in console.log I will get the old ID.

When I log event.target I have a good target with good id.
But when I want to get ID, I end up with the old one.
Anyone?

Comment: so when you console log event.target its the new dom element, but when you do event.target.id its the old id, and not the one from the new element? can you show the template

Comment: Is your event attached to a *person* level template? If so `this` will automatically be the data context of that template. This avoids the need to get the event target and is unambiguous.

Comment: Hi. Thx for answer. Here is my Jade code: http://jsfiddle.net/LLjmejry/
Event is attached to this template.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(event.target).attr('data-id')
```

I changed .data to .attr and it works